# Adding comments to text file used to copy files to multiple PCs via batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that copies data files to many user PCs based on a list kept in a text file. All of our PC names are numbers and would be much more efficient if I could add a comment to each line in the text file denoting whose PC it is.

I've tried both rem and :: with no success. Any suggestions?

**batch script code**

for /F "tokens=*" %%1 in (C:\targetPCs.txt) do (

    echo Copying files to %%1

    copy "\\server4\data\Files\Cube\cube.mdc" "\\%%1\Cube"

    )

**targetPCs.txt sample**

NY-PC-421

NY-PC-718

NY-PC-111

NY-PC-601

Comment: Start comment lines with semicolon

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in a couple of posts so you could find the answer by a simple search, anyway you can use the eol parameter to ignore line starting with # by example

batch script code

```
for /F "eol=# tokens=*" %%1 in (C:\targetPCs.txt) do ( 
echo Copying files to %%1 
copy "\\server4\data\Files\Cube\cube.mdc" "\\%%1\Cube" 
)
```

targetPCs.txt sample

```
#John's pc
NY-PC-421
#server 12
NY-PC-718
#etc etc
NY-PC-111 
NY-PC-601
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the PC names cannot include spaces. So you can simply append the owner's name to each line, with at least one intervening space. Then modify your FOR /F to keep just the first token.

**targetPCs.txt**

```
NY-PC-421 Bruce
NY-PC-718 Joanie
NY-PC-111 Stuart
NY-PC-601 Mary
```

**batch script**

```
for /F "tokens=1" %%1 in (C:\targetPCs.txt) do (
  echo Copying files to %%1
  copy "\\server4\data\Files\Cube\cube.mdc" "\\%%1\Cube"
)
```

Or you could parse both the PC name and the owner name to use in the message:

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %%1 in (C:\targetPCs.txt) do (
  echo Copying files to %%1 [%%2]
  copy "\\server4\data\Files\Cube\cube.mdc" "\\%%1\Cube"
)
```